# AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'string'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Since I am new to Python and Flask I am stuck. Currently I am following a video course called Learning flask.
I have created a model but when I try to start the app I get error

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

db = SQLAlchemy()

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    uid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key =True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.string(100))
    lastname = db.Column(db.string(100))
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    pwdhash = db.Column(db.String(54))

    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, email, password):
        self.firstname = firstname.title()
        self.lastname = lastname.title()
        self.email = email.lower()
        self.set_password(password)

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.pwdhash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.pwdhash, password)
```

```
(venv)smurf@tesla:~/WorkInProgress/learning-flask$ python routes.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "routes.py", line 2, in <module>
    from models import db
  File "/home/smurf/WorkInProgress/learning-flask/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    class User(db.Model):
  File "/home/smurf/WorkInProgress/learning-flask/models.py", line 9, in User
    firstname = db.Column(db.string(100))
AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'string'
```

Comment: EEhmmm looks like i used "string" instead of "String" =(

Answer (score 6):

String should be capitalized

```
firstname = db.Column(db.String(100))
lastname = db.Column(db.String(100))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

Needs an engine defined. So something like  `db = SQLAlchemy(app)` will provide a model. You need to define the engine config e.g. 'app' and pass it to the Call.

Also as suggested above you will need to fix the syntax errors too.